# Understanding Partial Sub-Classes

Tags: c#

I'm organizing my program into Classes.

I have **Controls** `class` with methods for the GUI, and **Generate** `class` with methods for calculating different outputs.

---

My question is are the **Audio** `partial classes` in this example linked to each other or are they their own separate classes?

Since one is under `Controls` and the other is under `Generate`. I'm looking to keep them separate.

I need them as `partial` because I have code spread over multiple files.

---

**Controls**

```
public partial class Controls
{
    public partial class Audio //<- this
    {
        public partial class Codec
        {
            public class AAC 
            {
                public static void MyMethod()
                { 
                    //... 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Generate**

```
public partial class Generate
{
    public partial class Audio //<- this
    {
       public class BitRate 
       {
           public static String MyMethod()
           { 
               //... 
           }
       }
    }
}
```

---

Call a **Controls** Method

```
Controls.Audio.Codec.AAC.MyMethod()
```

Call a **Generate** Method

```
Generate.Audio.BitRate.MyMethod()
```

Comment: "partial" classes are just a way to organize source code into different files - have nothing whatsoever to do with any kind of semantics, including scoping.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks for the info, this is the first time I've used them nested like this.

Comment: Generally, when you think about *"organizing [your] program into Classes"*, you should think about a class being a type of thing in your domain (e.g. a Codec or an audio stream). Your program will likely deal with multiple *instances* of these things. If all you want to do is have static methods in static classes, segregated by multipart names, there's no need for that complicated nesting, just use *Namespaces*. That's what they're for

Comment: @Flydog57 It's a lot clearer now, thanks.